# Why doesn't my Swift 3.0 decoder decodeInteger work for integers?

Tags: ios, swift3

So we've been using Groups for saving and retrieving some data across an extension and the main app and everything worked fine for Swift 2.3 but then we updated to Swift 3.0 and got some issues.

The current implementation that gives us issues is like following:

```
open class SomeClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
  open var someVar: Int!

  open func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.someVar, forKey:"someVar")
  }

  public required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    // this is where it breaks
    self.someVar = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "someVar") 
  }

}
```

The following error is thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeInt32ForKey:]: value for key (someVar) is not an integer number'
```

The funny thing is the old implementation for Swift 2.3 works without any issues: `self.someVar = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "someVar") as! Int` (I've understood from other posts that this would not work...)

So what could I be doing wrong? It should be said that the original value is retrieved from a float and cast to an int.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the assumed `encode` variant is the one that takes `Any?`, therefore your integer will be encoded as an object (`NSNumber`). I would convert that implictly unwrapped optional to a non-optional first. That should help.

Comment: @Sulthan In Swift 3.0 we only have encode, we can't encodeInt. Could you elaborate on what I should do?

Comment: That's the problem. Instead of `encodeInt` and `encodeObject` you have multiple `encode` methods, each of them taking a different type. The problem with `Int!` which is in this case considered as `Int?` is that it doesn't match `Int`. It will probably match `Any?`. It will be considered an object. `aCoder.encode(self.someVar!, ...` should work.

Comment: Just to backup what @Sulthan says: In Swift 3, implicitly unwrapped optionals are treated very much like regular optionals, and that was different in Swift 2.

Comment: @Sulthan Please put that in as an answer and elaborate on Martin Rs comment... I get that it gets treated as any but I don't quite get why ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is caused by multiple changes in Swift 3.

In Swift 3 the `encode` method is overloaded for every type. We have:

```
encode(Any?, forKey: String)
```

and

```
encode(Int, forKey: String)
```

The compiler chooses the correct method depending on the type of the first parameter (in Swift 2 you had two different method names therefore the type information was not needed).

You are putting `Int!` there. The behavior for Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals in Swift 3 changed due to [Swift Evolution 0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

If you read the changes, you can note that converting an IUO into a regular optional is preferred over unwrapping, therefore converting to `Any?` is preferred over unwrapping into `Int`.

> However, the appearance of ! at the end of a property or variable declaration's type no longer indicates that the declaration has IUO type; rather, it indicates that (1) the declaration has optional type, and (2) the declaration has an attribute indicating that its value may be implicitly forced. (No human would ever write or observe this attribute, but we will refer to it as @_autounwrapped.)

The problem should be fixed by

```
aCoder.encode(self.someVar!, forKey:"someVar")
```

Answer (score 5):

First check if you have encoded data with older versions of swift, if this is the case you still need to use
    `aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "someVar")`

So a more complete solution in this case would be

```
aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int ?? aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
```

If this is not the case then please make sure "someVar" actually has a value set

Comment: We're developing so I've cleaned everything multiple times just to be sure that wasn't an issue, also we see that it has a value set when we use decodeObject() as? Int

Comment: So when using the old implementation in swift 3.0 it is still working? are you sure encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) is getting called?